# Rational Team Concert: Project areas and Team Areas

Tags: rtc, ibm-jazz

Year ago RTC was implemented in our organization. However the way our IT works is different from the RTC concept. 
We have  several development teams managing several applications. They work on a project and there might be inter dependency of one application on another.
Right now we have separate project area for separate applications.
E.g. There is a department A and there are several teams managing application Team X, Team Y , Team Z.
At present, Team X, Y and Z have separate Project Areas. However for certain projects Team X have to make changes in Team Y. 
In this case we have to give developer access to both PAs. He has to create enhancement in PA-X and other enhancement in PA-Y. Then he mentions dependencies in Task X that it should be implemented only after task y.
This is because RTC is integrated with other tool which is managed by Operations. 
And sync do not happen if tasks are from different project areas.

I have a query:
1. Can we create a PA with name A, and have team areas under it as X, Y and Z
2. The members of X, Y and Z should have limited access on each other codes.

Regards,

Comment: Please define "limited access": the access is usually defined at the component level, not at a folder within a component.